# Inject an instance of an IOptions<>

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, jwt, extension-methods, asp.net-core-webapi

I need to access the value of my JwtSettings. I try to inject an instance of an **IOptions<>** class into the constructor of my class, but I got the problem:

```
 public class JwtHandler : IJwtHandler
 {
    private readonly JwtSettings _jwtSettings;

    public JwtHandler(IOptions<JwtSettings> jwtSettings)
    {
        jwtSettings = _jwtSettings.Value;
    } 
 }
```

I have error:

```
The type or namespace name 'IOptions<>' could not be found 
(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

When Im adding the using:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
```

VS is telling me that it is unnecesary.

**Updated**: My Assemblies:

```
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens    
System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt
```

Comment: What if you specify full name `Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptions<JwtSettings>` ?

Comment: the same....namespace could not be found

Comment: Have you referenced the assembly with that namespace and type?

Comment: I have just added all my assemblies to question

Comment: Try adding a reference to packages `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration` and `Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions`.

Comment: You are most likely missing an assembly reference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IOptions<T>` is definitely in the `Microsoft.Extensions.Options` namespace, so that is the using you need:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options
```

As far as why it might be telling you it's unnecessary, that's a brain-scratcher. The only thing I can think of is that something is borked in your project. Open your project folder and delete the bin and obj directories. Then rebuild your project. If it's still not working, you may have a version conflict. Check any referenced projects, and if any are explicitly including `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration`, `Microsoft.AspNetCore`, etc. ensure that they're all referencing the same versions of the those NuGet packages.

Comment: I have checked all the assemblies and what was missing is that NuGet JwtBearer packages has been added just to WebApi, not to project with Infrastructure.....anyway thank for help and attention to missing assemblies, reference, NuGets....